# Docker-Compose - TheHive, Cortex, Elasticsearch using Cassandra - question regarding ES localhost listening

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm deploying in AWS Ubuntu instance, on a VM using this yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: cassandra:3.11
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: cassandra
    environment:
      - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1G
      - HEAP_NEWSIZE=1G
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=thp
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/data:/var/lib/cassandra/data
    networks:
      - Hive

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:7.11.1
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=hive
      - script.allowed_types= inline
      - thread_pool.search.queue_size=100000
      - thread_pool.write.queue_size=10000
      - gateway.recover_after_nodes=1
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
    networks:
      - Hive
  
  cortex:
    container_name: cortex
    image: thehiveproject/cortex:latest
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - 'JOB_DIRECTORY=/opt/cortex/jobs'
    ports:
      - '0.0.0.0:9001:9001'
    volumes:
      - ./cortex/application.conf:/etc/cortex/application.conf
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - ./cortex/log/:/var/log/cortex
      - /tmp:/tmp
      #- ./cortex/Cortex-Analyzers:/opt/cortex/analyzers
      #- .cortex/Cortex-Analyzers/analyzers.json:/opt/cortex/analyzers/analyzers.json
    privileged: true
    networks:
      - Hive
  
  thehive:
    container_name: thehive
    image: 'thehiveproject/thehive4:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
    ports:
      - '0.0.0.0:9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - ./thehive/application.conf:/etc/thehive/application.conf
      - ./thehive/data:/opt/thp/thehive/data
      - ./thehive/index:/opt/thp/thehive/index
    command:
      --cortex-port 9001
      --cortex-keys ${CORTEX_KEY}
    networks:
      - Hive
      
networks:
    Hive:
        driver: bridge
```

and additional 2 yml application.conf files for thehive and cortex. The problem I have is that when I look up docker instances using docker ps or docker compose ps I can see that cortex and thehive are on 0.0.0.0:9000 and 0.0.0.0:9001 respectively but elasticsearch only shows 9200/tcp, 9300/tcp. How can I get access to web interface of ES locally? I can't figure this out. Using netstat I can't find port 9200 or 9300 listening anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not natively come with a web interface. Elasticsearch exposes a REST api where third party interfaces can interact with.

One of the most popular tools for visualizing or viewing data in the elastic stack is Kibana which interfaces with Elasticsearch. See link for more details: https://www.elastic.co/kibana/

ES API Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-apis.html